# just get my mkr1000 in macOS Sierra 10.13 and no way to connect

Tags: mac-os, mkr1000

I have connected the device via USB, downloaded the latest version of Arduino IDE (1.8.5) installed (automatically offered) the drivers for the mkr, and there's nothing in the serial port selector besides the bluetooth. I've also installed the FTDI drivers but the same scenario.

What else can I try?

Error message:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino MKR1000"

Sketch uses 9624 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 262144 bytes.
Couldn't find a Board on the selected port. Check that you have the correct port selected.  If it is correct, try pressing the board's reset button after initiating the upload.
```

Seems like it is trying the bloutooth port

```
PORTS {/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port, /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port, } / {/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port, /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port, } => {}
```

UPDATE this is a system report screenshot:

[image]

Also the FTDI kext is loaded

```
sudo kextload /Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext
kextstat | grep FTDI                                      
  194    0 0xffffff7f85e62000 0x7000     0x7000     com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver (2.4.2) E16D9540-AF63-36AD-94C4-B1164FBD6078 <109 55 5 4 3 1>
```

Comment: Does plugging and unplugging the USB device cause any messages in the kernel debug messages to appear (`dmesg -w`, see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4170078)?

Comment: 007942.764202 Bluetooth USB Host Controller@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::forcePowerGated: allowing power level to float
007942.764217 Bluetooth USB Host Controller@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::forcePowerGated: kPowerStateSuspended completed with 0x00000000 after 0ms

Comment: the device is correctly listed in USB devices in settings

Comment: Which device is correctly listed? Can you edit your main question include logs and or a screenshot? Above messages indicate that you're seeing something about your Bluetooth controller? Or are those really the messages you get at the exact moment you plug/unplug the Arduino? (I'm trying to figure out here if the USB device is recognized at all, maybe your board is dead.)

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I've added a screenshot

Comment: So the MKR1000 gets listed somewhere in your Mac, but you cannot select it as a port in the Arduino IDE? Can you edit your question to include the output of `ls /dev/`. Also, maybe https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/13825/30175 is relevant?

Comment: well ls /dev/ is a very long result, a lot of ttyuX devices, I've already tried with FTDI drivers also

Comment: After rebooting, have no idea why, the device is listed on the list and I'm able to use it