# Tried to fix ports on Mac OS X Yosemite. Now nothing works

Tags: mac-os

I was having an issue very similar to this one:

[Arduino compatible's serial port not showing Mac OSX](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/arduino-compatibles-serial-port-not-showing-mac-osx)

Basically I have a clone (VISduino) and it's made with a different USB chip so it needed a driver. Installing the driver didn't help.

http://kiguino.moos.io/2014/12/31/how-to-use-arduino-nano-mini-pro-with-CH340G-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

Running:

```
 sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"
```

didn't help. So I decided to delete Arduino and reinstall. Then I went through all of the steps again.

Well.... now nothing works. Before doing this I could use:

- Adafruit metro
- An uno clone
- My genuine uno
- lightBlue Bean
- adafruit trinket and trinket pro
- adafruit trinket pro via USB
- digikey

[image]

I've reinstalled the drivers for these but NOTHING is working now. They were all working before. It just says Arduino Uno on COM1, or digikey on COM1 etc.

[image]

And of course my clone (vis duino) isn't working either.

How can I fix this?

[image]

The com ports just are not there.

Comment: That's clever - you've got your Mac to give you Windows device names...?!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: COM1 is what windows calls it.  I'd expect something like /dev/cu.modem-4d82f3a

Comment: well my mac is calling it com1 I posted a photo.

Comment: It's saying COM1 because you haven't (yet) selected a serial port to use.  This has nothing to do with the Arduino IDE - it's 100% to do with dodgy drivers.

Comment: Serial is greyed out. I tried deleting all Arduino files (except for my sketches which I put in another folder.) reinstalling and just trying to load blink on my  genuine uno.... same error.

Comment: Have you reviewed the questions shown as Linked or Related, in the right sidebar?  Eg,  “Arduino compatible's serial port not showing Mac OSX”, “No valid serial ports for Arduino UNO on Mac”, “Arduino compatible's serial port not showing Mac OSX”, “Arduino Nano no serial port for MacBook Air 2013”, and “Mac won't detect Serial Port for Leonardo”

Comment: Restarted for the 6th time and now it works WTF seriously.

Comment: Oh I did read all of those. It's working now but I have no idea why. Ugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting all of the Arduino files and the Arduino app. I put my sketched folder aside but deleted all libraries.

Restarted the computer.

Installed Arduino fresh.

Restarted the computer.

Installed the drivers.

Ran the command.

Restarted the computer.

Restarted the computer.

Restarted the computer.

Then it worked.